# Как переписать асинхронный код на синхронный?

Tags: flutter, dart

Мне поставили задачу переписать мой же асинхронный код, на синхронный. Пробовал тупо убрать все async/await и Future, но получал ошибку - **Instance of 'Future<String?>'**

Вот мой асинхронный код -

```
class SecureStorage {
  final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
   Future writeSecureData (String key, String value) async{
    var  writeData = await _storage.write(key: 'count', value: '123');
    // print(writeData);
    return writeData;
  }
   Future readSecureData (String key) async{
    var readData = await _storage.read(key: 'count');
    print(readData);
    return readData;
  }
}
```

Вся структура кода - файл tes

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
      color: Colors. black12,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => SecureStorage().writeSecureData('count', '123'), child: Text('write')),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => SecureStorage().readSecureData('count'), child: Text('read')),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecureStorage {

  final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
   writeSecureData (String key, String value) {
    var  writeData = _storage.write(key: 'count', value: '123');
    // print(writeData);
    return writeData;
  }
   readSecureData (String key) {
    var readData = _storage.read(key: 'count');
    print(readData);
    return readData;
  }
}
```

файл main

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      // '/': (context) => Auth(),
      '/': (context) => Test(),
      '/home': (context) => Homepage()
    },

  )
  );
}
```